# How to open a C# call stack (string) in Visual Studio 2019 Professional?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2019

OK, suppose I have a C# string for a callstack for a runtime Exception (copied to the clipboard from Azure Application Insights - but it could be from everywhere).  Note that this is not from an active debug session in Visual Studio.

Now I want to open this callstack in Visual Studio.  How can I do this, without having to manually read the string, find the top of the stack, and then try to open it?

Surely there should be a built-in feature, or an extension, that can "open callstack"?

Comment: Opening the file and going to the line is what I normally do...

Comment: @xanatos Yes, this is what I normally do, but this is a huge pain with large call stacks.  There should be a "quick nav" type of experience where you can just paste in the desired call stack and "go there instantly"

Comment: FWIW I tried installing Stack Trace Explorer, which is targeting this scenario.  Unfortunately it doesn't work for Application Insights calls tacks and in general is pretty buggy

Comment: @AX If all you have is the string then you'll need to navigate the stack manually. For any serious debugging you should save a crash dump file, instead, which can then be opened in VS (or WinDbg) with access to the full context and debugger tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual studio 2022 this feature has been added.

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> (keep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> down while pressing <kbd>E</kbd> and then <kbd>S</kbd>).

Via the menu you can reach it via `View` -> `Other Windows` -> `Stack Trace Explorer`.

Once the window is open, you can click on any of the lines and you will navigate to the spot instantly. Saves a ton of navigation time!

If you have an older version of Visual studio with JetBrains Resharper the keystroke is Extra-Terrestrial (that's how I remembered it) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get the dump file of it. You can check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/vs-callstack).

Then, use VS debugger to [debug the dump file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-dump-files?view=vs-2019). Otherwise, you have to manually navigate to the string line.